# Highlighting corresponding spans, and add an other color when one of them is empty

Tags: javascript, hover, highlight

I would like to create a JS script to highlight the spans that have a corresponding index in two different containers. I managed to create that script and it works, however, I would like to add one detail : when one of the two corresponding span is empty the other one should be highlighted in a different color.

I tried this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Textes en Parallèle</title>

<style>
body {
    display: flex;
}

.text-container {
    flex: 1;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    max-height: 300px;
}

.highlight {
    background-color: yellow;
}

.highlight-empty {
       background-color: #8eff8e; /* Couleur verte pour le surlignage */
   }

</style>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="text-container" id="text1">
        <!-- first version of the text -->
        <span>span1.</span> common text
        <span>span 2.</span>
        <span></span>
    </div>
    <div class="text-container" id="text2">
        <!-- second version of the text -->
        <span>corresponding span 1.</span> common text
        <span>corresp span 2</span>
        <span>add => empty span on the other side</span>
    </div>
    <script>

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        const textContainers1 = document.getElementById('text1').querySelectorAll('span');
        const textContainers2 = document.getElementById('text2').querySelectorAll('span');

        function addHighlight(index) {
            textContainers1[index].classList.add('highlight');
            textContainers2[index].classList.add('highlight');
        }

        function removeHighlight(index) {
            textContainers1[index].classList.remove('highlight');
            textContainers2[index].classList.remove('highlight');
        }

        textContainers1.forEach((paragraph1, index) => {
            paragraph1.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
                if (textContainers2[index].innerHTML.trim() === '') {
                    textContainers2[index].classList.add('highlight-empty');
                }
                addHighlight(index);
            });

            paragraph1.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
                removeHighlight(index);
                textContainers2[index].classList.remove('highlight-empty');
            });
        });

        textContainers2.forEach((paragraph2, index) => {
            paragraph2.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
                if (textContainers1[index].innerHTML.trim() === '') {
                    textContainers1[index].classList.add('highlight-empty');
                }
                addHighlight(index);
            });

            paragraph2.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
                removeHighlight(index);
                textContainers1[index].classList.remove('highlight-empty');
            });
        });
    });

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I don't understand why my add => empty span on the other side is still in yellow and not in green when I over. Do you have an idea what's wrong with my JS conditions ?

Thank you so much in advance,

Comment: You're attempting to highlight an empty space, so so there is nothing there to highlight.

Answer (score 1):

There's 2 issues here. Firstly your logic only adds the `.highlight-empty` class to the empty `span`. Therefore no difference is shown. You need to amend the logic to also add that class to the `span` which *does* have content, so that it has an effect.

Secondly, you need to make the `.highlight-empty` class in your CSS have a higher specificity so that it overrides the `.highlight` class. The simple way to do this is by adding another selector to it.

Here's a working version with these changes made:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const textContainers1 = document.getElementById('text1').querySelectorAll('span');
  const textContainers2 = document.getElementById('text2').querySelectorAll('span');

  function addHighlight(index) {
    textContainers1[index].classList.add('highlight');
    textContainers2[index].classList.add('highlight');
  }

  function removeHighlight(index) {
    textContainers1[index].classList.remove('highlight');
    textContainers2[index].classList.remove('highlight');
  }

  textContainers1.forEach((paragraph1, index) => {
    paragraph1.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
      if (textContainers2[index].innerHTML.trim() === '' || textContainers1[index].innerHTML.trim() === '') {
        textContainers1[index].classList.add('highlight-empty');
        textContainers2[index].classList.add('highlight-empty');
      }
      addHighlight(index);
    });

    paragraph1.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
      removeHighlight(index);
      textContainers2[index].classList.remove('highlight-empty');
    });
  });

  textContainers2.forEach((paragraph2, index) => {
    paragraph2.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
      if (textContainers2[index].innerHTML.trim() === '' || textContainers1[index].innerHTML.trim() === '') {
        textContainers1[index].classList.add('highlight-empty');
        textContainers2[index].classList.add('highlight-empty');
      }
      addHighlight(index);
    });

    paragraph2.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
      removeHighlight(index);
      textContainers1[index].classList.remove('highlight-empty');
    });
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
}

.text-container {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  max-height: 300px;
}

.highlight {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.highlight.highlight-empty {
  background-color: #8eff8e;
  /* Couleur verte pour le surlignage */
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="text-container" id="text1">
    <span>span1.</span> common text
    <span>span 2.</span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
  <div class="text-container" id="text2">
    <span>corresponding span 1.</span> common text
    <span>corresp span 2</span>
    <span>add => empty span on the other side</span>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Textes en Parallèle</title>

<style>
body {
    display: flex;
}

.text-container {
    flex: 1;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    max-height: 300px;
}

.highlight {
    background-color: yellow;
}

.highlight-empty {
       background-color: #8eff8e; /* Couleur verte pour le surlignage */
   }

</style>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="text-container" id="text1">
        <!-- first version of the text -->
        <span>span1.</span> common text
        <span>span 2.</span>
        <span></span>
        <span>span4</span>
    </div>
    <div class="text-container" id="text2">
        <!-- second version of the text -->
        <span>corresponding span 1.</span> common text
        <span>corresp span 2</span>
        <span>add => empty span on the other side</span>
        <span></span>
    </div>
    <script>

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        const textContainers1 = document.getElementById('text1').querySelectorAll('span');
        const textContainers2 = document.getElementById('text2').querySelectorAll('span');

        function addHighlight(index) {
            textContainers1[index].classList.add('highlight');
            textContainers2[index].classList.add('highlight');
        }

        function removeHighlight(index) {
            textContainers1[index].classList.remove('highlight');
            textContainers2[index].classList.remove('highlight');
        }

        textContainers1.forEach((paragraph1, index) => {
            paragraph1.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
                if (textContainers2[index].innerHTML.trim() === '') {
                    textContainers1[index].classList.add('highlight-empty');
                }
                addHighlight(index);
            });

            paragraph1.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
                removeHighlight(index);
                textContainers1[index].classList.remove('highlight-empty');
            });
        });

        textContainers2.forEach((paragraph2, index) => {
            paragraph2.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
                if (textContainers1[index].innerHTML.trim() === '') {
                    textContainers2[index].classList.add('highlight-empty');
                }
                addHighlight(index);
            });

            paragraph2.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
                removeHighlight(index);
                textContainers2[index].classList.remove('highlight-empty');
            });
        });
    });

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

##In this case we only need to add class and the condition to highlight different span in case of any of corresponding span is empty  ##

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Textes en Parallèle</title>

<style>
body {
    display: flex;
}

.text-container {
    flex: 1;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    max-height: 300px;
}

.highlight-different {
    background-color: red !important;
}

.highlight {
    background-color: yellow;
}

.highlight-empty {
       background-color: #8eff8e; /* Couleur verte pour le surlignage */
   }

</style>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="text-container" id="text1">
        <!-- first version of the text -->
        <span>span1.</span> common text
        <span>span 2.</span>
        <span>   </span>
    </div>
    <div class="text-container" id="text2">
        <!-- second version of the text -->
        <span>corresponding span 1.</span> common text
        <span>corresp span 2</span>
        <span>add => empty span on the other side</span>
    </div>
    <script>

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        const textContainers1 = document.getElementById('text1').querySelectorAll('span');
        const textContainers2 = document.getElementById('text2').querySelectorAll('span');

        function addHighlight(index,different=false) {
            const highlight_type=different?'highlight-different':'highlight';
            textContainers1[index].classList.add(highlight_type);
            textContainers2[index].classList.add(highlight_type);
        }

        function removeHighlight(index) {
            textContainers1[index].classList.remove('highlight');
            textContainers2[index].classList.remove('highlight');
            textContainers1[index].classList.remove('highlight-different');
            textContainers2[index].classList.remove('highlight-different');
        }

        textContainers1.forEach((paragraph1, index) => {
            paragraph1.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
                if (textContainers2[index].innerHTML.trim() === '') {
                    addHighlight(index,true);
                    // textContainers2[index].classList.add('highlight-empty');
                }
                addHighlight(index);
            });

            paragraph1.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
                removeHighlight(index);
                // textContainers2[index].classList.remove('highlight-empty');
            });
        });

        textContainers2.forEach((paragraph2, index) => {
            paragraph2.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
                if (textContainers1[index].innerHTML.trim() === '') {
                    // textContainers1[index].classList.add('highlight-empty');
                    addHighlight(index,true);
                    
                }
                addHighlight(index);
            });

            paragraph2.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
                removeHighlight(index);
                // textContainers1[index].classList.remove('highlight-empty');
            });
        });
    });

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```